# Is the first “only” in “They should only know that this is the only place...” correct

Tags: word-choice

> They should only know that this is the only place that sells coffee.

I don’t get what the first “only” means in that statement my friend made.

Comment: The writer of this awkward sentence may be trying to say that **all they need to know is that....** but the sentence would be improved by omitting the first **only**.

Comment: Omitting the first *only* would change the meaning of the sentence entirely. It's not phrased very well, but you can't just remove it.